# perl print OUT and print not showing the same data

Tags: perl

Hi what would the reason be for `print` and `print $fh` showing different result. In this case the .csv  output to screen is 152 lines, but when it is printed to $fh it stops at line 128..

```
print  join (',', @col) . "\n";
print $fh join (',', @col) . "\n";
```

Comment: Are you checking the file after a point at which it should be flushed?  Perhaps that output is still being buffered?  (this is even more likely if the size of the file is a power of 2 like 4096 or something)

Comment: Hi i have just noticed that the rest of the output is all in the last cell of line 128, so all the data is there  for some reason!

Comment: Are those two lines really adjacent like that? Can you fill `@col` with something simpler like `'A' .. 'F'` and get the same result? What do you mean exactly by *"the rest of the output is all in the last cell"*? Can you show some sample output?

Comment: I found the problem in a column someone had written a paragraph with a comma in the middle. ill have to do a grep to get rid of them at the beginning of the scripts.

Comment: @user3360439: That doesn't explain why the behaviour is different when you specify a file handle. Please write the answer up properly as a solution and accept it, so that others can see that the problem has been resolved and that it coiuld be useful if they have a similar problem

Comment: Though removing the comma from a paragraph in a cell gave me the correct output, i do not know why this only affected the filehandle and not the screen print..

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this and have a tail running on the $fh, this behavior will happen because most systems buffer output by default.  If you want to turn it off turn off buffering

```
select $fh;
$|=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

To be absolutely unambiguous, I would write the second line as follows:

```
print {$fh} join(',', @col), "\n";
```

Then see whether this solves the issue.

Answer (score -2):

You have a comma rather than a concatenation after the join command there.

It is conceivable that what you're getting is more exactly join((',', @col), "\n") in the second case.  This flies in the face of logic because we think of functions as requiring pareens

join(',', "dog"), "cat" looks like it should yield a two entry list ("dog", "cat")

but if you did join ',', "dog", "cat" you would expect a single string "dog,cat"

Thanks to your extra space after the join, I wonder if it is seeing it in the latter pattern instead of the former.  Try concatenating to the join instead of using a comma and removing the space and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No Luck i'd afraid. why would the 2 print lines produce a different result?

Comment: That is a wild stab in the dark. There's no reason a space after the function name should cause this behaviour as both statements are the same after the file handle. In any case whitespace at that point is ignored in Perl, and it would be bizarre if it caused the parentheses to be ignored